# How to compute a natural join?

Tags: relational-algebra

Could someone explain to me what is going on here and how to solve this problem?

Suppose relation R(A,B) has the tuples:

```
A B
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

and the relation S(B,C,D) has tuples:

```
B C D
2 4 6
4 6 8
4 7 9
```

Compute the natural join of R and S. Then, identify which of the following tuples is in the
natural join 
 R |><| S. You may assume each tuple has schema (A,B,C,D).

I don't know what a natural join truly means. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Show that you've put some effort into figuring it out yourself before you get help from others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A natural join is joining ("sticking together") elements from two relations where there is a match. In this example

- (1, **2**) matches (**2**, 4, 6) so you get (1, 2, 4, 6)
- (3, **4**) matches (**4**, 6, 8) so you get (3, 4, 6, 8)
- (3, **4**) matches (**4**, 7, 9) so you get (3, 4, 7, 9)

So the natural join is {(1, 2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 6, 8), (3, 4, 7, 9)}

Comment: natural join matches on PK and here only B is PK

Comment: Putting things in quotes does not explain them. And you are using "joining" in a row sense, which is not explained either. Neither is "matches". No doubt your enumeration of the source of the result rows & the everyday meanings of the terms are suggestive & helpful, but you really aren't giving an explanation to the enumeration.

Comment: @require_once PKs (& other constraints) are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume R(A,B) is the master, S(B,C,D) is the detail and B is the foreign key.

SQL: select * from R, S where R.B = S.B

Then the result is:

A B C D

1 2 4 6

3 4 6 8

3 4 7 9

Comment: PKs (& other constraints) are irrelevant.