# How to compute a natural join??? 5

Tags: relational-algebra

Table R (A, C) contains the following entries:

A   C

3   3

6   4

2   3

3   5

7   1

Table S (B, C, D) following

B  C  D

5  1  6

1  5  8

4  3  9

Calculate the natural join of R and S. Which of the lines would be the result? Each resulting string has the following schema (A, B, C, D).

Please help!!!

Comment: Common attribute is `C`, no?

Comment: Yes, but not all values common and value `3` is present 2 times, so I think that it's not a match. But he could create 2 tables and run a query to get the right result.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Suggest you learn what join does. user3752224 too, also show us what you have tried or know so far.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547014/how-to-compute-a-natural-join). So your answer should be: {(3,4,3,9),(2,4,3,9),(3,1,5,8),(7,5,1,6)}

A B C D

3 4 3 9

2 4 3 9

3 1 5 8

7 5 1 6